# Allowed to Extend a baseClass and Implement an interface

Tags: typescript

Went from something like this:
    export class Duck implements IDuckService

To:
    export class Duck extends BaseDuck implements IDuckService

I'm getting a TypeError when I try to run.

Is extending and implementing allowed in Typescript?

Errors in console are like this my objects aren't really ducks so they are edited.
[12:15:59.033] TypeError: b is undefined 
[12:15:59.057] Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DuckServiceProvider <- DuckService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/unpr?p0=DuckServiceProvider%20%3C-%20DuckService

Comment: The actual text of the error would be a normal sort of thing to include in a question.

Comment: Your error is about `b`? What's `b`? It looks like you have some kind of Angular problem, not a TypeScript problem.

Comment: Okay new to TypeScript and Angular I'll try to figure out what B is thanks again.

Comment: var DuckService = (function (_super) {
                        __extends(DuckService, _super);  
      
calls...
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;   //this is the b that is undefined which seems to involved in this bug report http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/627
    d.prototype = new __();
};

Comment: Reading about the ordering issues made me wonder about my BundleConfig.cs file.  Turned out I had put BaseDuck.js above Duck in the bundle but Duck.js was actually in the script bundle twice the other time was above BaseDuck.js.  That seems to have been the cause of my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed.

Most often, this happens because you did something like:

1. Write `BaseDuck.ts`, compile to `BaseDuck.js`
2. Write `Duck.ts`, compile to `Duck.js`
3. Include `Duck.js` *but not `BaseDuck.js`* in a `<script>` tag in your webpage. Both need to be there.